# How to correctly imbed YouTube videos in HTML

Tags: html, video, iframe, youtube

I was trying to imbed a Youtube video in my website using `iframe` tag. However, many warnings appear on the console when using Chrome, such as:

`Reading cookie in cross-site context will be blocked in future Chrome versions`

I also read online that using `iframe` is discouraged due to security reasons.

To avoid breaking changes and security issues, I wonder if there is a better and safe way to imbed a YouTube video in my website apart from adding a `video` tag, as blocking external cookies is not possible as of my knowledge.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe
      width="560"
      height="315"
      src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ?si=huEs0X_fKX95LMeh"
      title="YouTube video player"
      frameborder="0"
      allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share"
      allowfullscreen
    ></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is the complete warning log:

```
Reading cookie in cross-site context will be blocked in future Chrome versions

Cookies with the SameSite=None; Secure and not Partitioned attributes that operate in cross-site contexts are third-party cookies. In future Chrome versions, reading third-party cookies will be blocked. This behavior protects user data from cross-site tracking.
```

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<meta>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-meta-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification. The same is true for all self-closing HTML tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Go to the video on the YouTube web site
- Click `Share`
- Click `Embed`
- Copy and paste the HTML you are offered into your own page.

Reference: https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/171780?hl=en

Comment: Sorry, at first I thought this solved my answer but using the link you provided still generates the same warnings: Reading cookie in cross-site context will be blocked in future Chrome versions. I added more details to the question that were lacking before

Comment: Edit: Using https://www.youtube-nocookie.com instead of https://www.youtube.com does the trick, as provided in the same link, thank you!